# Task management software for Ubuntu?

Tags: project-management, task-management

I am part of a large F/OSS project; as part of my role I need to assign tasks to people.

As such, I am trying to find software that allows me to set a task (priority, due date, description, etc) and send it via email to someone. I would preferably like software that can send an email which can be marked by the assignee as done, and notify me of this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Redmine (as posted by rob) might be better suited to your question (it uses mail) also have a look at [gantproject](http://www.ganttproject.biz/) and see if that is what you are looking for.

From their webite:

```
GanttProject is a cross-platform desktop tool for project 
scheduling and management. It runs on Windows, Linux and MacOSX, 
it is free and its code is opensource. What can it do?

Create work breakdown structure, draw dependencies, 
define milestones. 
Assign human resources to work on tasks, 
see their allocation on the Resource Load chart.
Share projects with your colleagues using WebDAV.
```

and an image:

[image: images1]

Answer (score 2):

You may be better off with popular web-based task or issue tracking solution such as [redmine](http://www.redmine.org) or [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) instead of a desktop application. Just a thought.

Comment: I'd recommend Redmine as well, you can customise the ticket issues, so you can set tasks, assign people to them. Whenever they are updated it will email them. You can set workflows so you can control who changes the status. Finally for your F/OSS project with Redmine you will have a built in bug tracking system, version management system and you'll be able to link to which ever version control system you are using. All in the one package!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [proofhub](http://www.proofhub.com) ? It lets you add to-do's and assign it to your team with a milestone set for due date. you can easily integrate it with your email. Get notified of every update of task completion or status change of any task assigned. We have been using for few months and we can't imagine our project management without it. There is 30 days free trial available.